# Git Commit to push

Tags: git, pycharm

First at all I'm sorry for my bad English. I am really new in Git.
So I downloaded PyCharm Professional 2020.2 and I connected Git per Url to my repertory.
My question is, do I have to commit every time when I want to push or upload my file to Git?
It's only working when I am doing it, Am I just dumm or is there a better way?

Thank You all.

Comment: Yes. You push commits, so if you don't have commits, you can't push.

Comment: This book https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 can help in git learning.